# Sort an array of objects but ignore 'THE' in the name

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

I have the following array of ojects,

```
{ name: 'Hundred Monkeys',
 address: '52 High Street Glastonbury BA6 9DY' },
{ name: 'J.C Thomas and sons ltd',
 address: 'Thomas Way Glastonbury BA69LU' },
{ name: 'Lady Of The Silver Wheel',
 address: '13 Market Place Glastonbury BA6 9HH' },
{ name: 'The Chalice Well',
 address: '85-89 Chilkwell Street Glastonbury BA6 8DD' },
{ name: 'The Glastonbury Wire Studio',
 address: '48a High Street Glastonbury BA6 9DX' },
{ name: 'The Isle of Avalon Foundation',
 address: 'The Glastonbury Experience, 2-4 High Street, Glastonbury BA6 9DU' },
{ name: 'The King Arthur',
address: '31-33 Benedict Street Glastonbury BA6 9NB' },
```

I sort it via

```
VenueList.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
```

But all the names beginning with 'THE' get sorted under T. Can I add a conditional to this sort to ignore the first word if it is 'The' and how would I go about that? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create new strings which don't have the data you want to ignore in them.

Then compare those.

```
VenueList.sort(function (a, b) {
    a = a.name.replace(/^The /, "");
    b = b.name.replace(/^The /, "");
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

(Adjust regex as desired (e.g. to make it case insensitive or add additional words))

Comment: Works great Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use [decorate-sort-undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to create a tuple that includes the string you wish to sort by for each object. Then you sort using the key. Afterwards you extract the object from the tuples.

**Note:** it seems like a lot of unnecessary mappings, but it saves the need to extract the correct keys on each comparison.

```js
const VenueList = [{"name":"Hundred Monkeys","address":"52 High Street Glastonbury BA6 9DY"},{"name":"J.C Thomas and sons ltd","address":"Thomas Way Glastonbury BA69LU"},{"name":"Lady Of The Silver Wheel","address":"13 Market Place Glastonbury BA6 9HH"},{"name":"The Chalice Well","address":"85-89 Chilkwell Street Glastonbury BA6 8DD"},{"name":"The Glastonbury Wire Studio","address":"48a High Street Glastonbury BA6 9DX"},{"name":"The Isle of Avalon Foundation","address":"The Glastonbury Experience, 2-4 High Street, Glastonbury BA6 9DU"},{"name":"The King Arthur","address":"31-33 Benedict Street Glastonbury BA6 9NB"}];

const result = VenueList
  .map((o) => [o.name.replace(/^The\s+/, ''), o]) // create a tuple of ['King Arthur', {"name":"The King Arthur","address": ...}]
  .sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b))
  .map(([, o]) => o); // extract the original object {"name":"The King Arthur","address": ...}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: On first glance it looks like a lot of unnecessary work, but as you mentioned in the note you added, especially in larger arrays, it would probably perform better than calling replace on both strings for every comparison the sort algorithm makes.

Comment: This options seems a little above my skillset.. What is happening in the line `.map(([, o]) => o);` the , on it's own I haven't seen before.. Thanks

Comment: @PaulLeppard - I've added comments to the map lines. You might want to read about [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).